# Copying Notes from one sheet to another. Importrange?

Tags: google-apps-script

OK, still rookie coder but getting better. Able to modify codes but not write most of them myself yet. Here is my current problem.

I run a small business and we use google sheets as  our CRM (its faster  and  easier for us to do it this way) I have a master sheet that I bring in with =importrange everyone else jobs. It works perfect, makes my life real easy but there is one thing I can not get to come over. That  is the notes stored in a cell. I have to actually open their sheet to view the notes. So I am trying to get a script that would update the notes down the importedrange. Then each day when I go over their info I push a button and it would write the notes from the other persons sheet onto my sheet, can just write over the last note and replace it.

I made an example with 3 sheets (all made editable for everyone) since I can't post our actual business sheets to work with. I should be able to modify it and transfer to my actual sheets after some help.

(Master Sheet) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TMNyohd5Vtn3p9cpLebmZASt2TzbWL80fIesCu89-ig/edit?usp=sharing

(Employee 1)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n4iFXGuC7yG1XC-UIbuT9VrQ7rJWngPkDCv0vsvDed4/edit?usp=sharing

(Employee 2)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EJVa5TgF6UkLhiLtfQ6o7BzpdzXDGcVhkibLCYwlfAU/edit?usp=sharing

Links are provided to each other sheet on the top of the master sheet. This is above my head so I won't try to butcher the code below lol. Here is a function I found but don't know how to implement it to use with import range.

```
function getNotes(rangeAddress) {
  // returns notes inserted with Insert > Note from one cell or a range of cells
  // usage:
  //    =getNotes("A1"; GoogleClock())
  //    =getNotes("A1:B5"; GoogleClock())
  // see /docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0xgeLRpFPzqc/discussion
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRangeByName(rangeAddress);
  if (!range) return '#N/A: invalid range. Usage:      =getNotes("A1:B5"; GoogleClock())';

  var notesArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < range.getHeight(); i++) {
    notesArray[i] = new Array();
    for (var j = 0; j < range.getWidth(); j++) {
      notesArray[i][j] = range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).getComment();
    }    
  }
  return notesArray;
}
```

So The  code I would want it to read the note from "Employee 1" sheet and write it onto the "Master" sheet in the correct cell. Since it is an =importrange the orientation of the cells will always be the same on both sheets, just needs to pick the starting cell and go down the list. I want to make it work with the button I put on the top of the master sheet on each tab.

Answer (score 3):

This script uses outdated methods. For example, `GoogleClock()` [is gone](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0_4cW1sZMO78/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2F_4cW1sZMO78).

Please see my other response to [your similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343110/is-it-even-possible-to-copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-with-a-script-import) for a possible solution.