# Is it even possible to copy data from one sheet to another with a script? ImportRange style?

Tags: google-apps-script

Ive searched for 2 days, can't seem to find the answer or anyone that is even doing something kinda like this. I am trying to bring my employees sheets over to my "Master sheet" with a script. I need to keep the formatting and the notes in the cells.

Best I can find is I can open their spread sheets and copy it to my master, but for 8 employees this will be a pain if I need to do this multiple times a day. I would like to just build a function that I can run my script from the "master sheet" and have it write over the last data in their tab. But I want to be able to do this from within my master sheet. I am the owner of all the sheets but this is becoming a pain.

```
function copyCell() {
  var os = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1n4iFXGuC7yG1XC-UIbuT9VrQ7rJWngPkDCv0vsvDed4');
  var sheets = os.getSheets();
  var existingNote;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var jobnumber = sheets.getRange("C2:C").getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < jobnumber.length; i++)
   if (jobnumber[i][0] == sheets){

    existingNote = sheets.getRange("C" + (i+2)).getNote();
    sheets.getRange("C" + (i+2)).ss.setNote(existingNote);
    }

};
```

Someone please let me know if it is possible and maybe reference a script I can see to be able to modify to fit my needs. Thanks for any help.

Comment: ImportRange honestly works but I don't get the notes and that is half of what I need.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution for copying the notes associated with a range of cells. And pasting them onto a similar-sized range of cells.

To copy the notes you can use `getNotes()`. [Docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNotes()).

To paste the notes you can use `setNotes()`. [Docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNotes(Object)).

Ths sample code in this documentation is pretty good if you need to add it into your script.

If you have a script you'd like to share am happy to help you make it work properly.

---

**Edit**

Something like this:

```
function transferNotes() {
  // Get notes (not comments) from the source spreadsheet
  var sourceSpreadheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID_of_source_spreadsheet');
  var sourceTab = sourceSpreadheet.getSheetByName('Name_source_tab');
  var sourceRange = sourceTab.getRange('Source_range_address'); // e.g. "A:D"
  var notes = sourceRange.getNotes();

  // Post the notes to the target spreadsheet
  var targetSpreadheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID_of_target_spreadsheet');
  var targetTab = targetSpreadheet.getSheetByName('Name_target_tab');
  var targetRange = targetTab.getRange('Target_range_address'); // Should be the same dimensions as sourceRange
  targetRange.setNotes(notes); 
}
```

Comment: But how do I get it to pull from a whole different spreadsheet.  When I try to do that it doesn't seem to let me. Not just another tab but a whole different google spread sheet.